# Large data handling in Excel, producing graphs from "scrambled" data

Tags: excel, sorting, graph

I have a project here where I receive large data files in Excel. I have to sort these and produce graphs, showing trends over time etc. 
The data I receive is "scrambled" in the sense that it is data for several different "profiles" at once, and I first have to manually sort each of these into their own tab in excel. I then use pivot tables and graphs to interpret the data.

Is there a way to produce graphs that read this data directly from the source file? The graphs would have to sort out data based on parameters from several different columns at once, to make sure it only reads data for a specific "profile" under certain conditions.

I realize that Excel might not be powerful enough to do this on its own, and that I may have to look into some actual programming, but I need some help on where to look.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Solved with Tableau data analytics software

Comment: Probably something powerquery/Power BI could also handle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, if anyone comes across this post:
I did try Pentaho but had little luck with it. 
I came across a big data analytics software called Tableau, which looks extremely promising. Super easy to use, I didn't have to modify my data in any way, and it produces the graphs I need.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are so many ways to tackle this problem, probably a good start point is reading about ETL. In a nutshell what you really want to do is to process each file as they arrive clean stuff that you need, maybe enrich your data on multiple occasions. and incrementally store them in a database. so far this stuff can be done using an ETL tool. A good example is Pentaho ETL tool.(but there are many )

After you are done with loading data into marts. The second thing that you need is a data-visualization tool. this will enable you to create fancy graphs and report/insights out of them

You can simply search for these tools and evaluate what works for you based on your data volume and performance requirements.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely look into this. 
Am I understanding you correctly in that you first want me to use an ETL tool to produce a database, and then a separate data-visualization tool? 

My data is already in a sort of database format in Excel. Is it not possible to use a data-visualization tool directly?